# Firefox Extension util/match-pattern subdirectory

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a browser extension for both Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. The extension provides functionality for Oracle APEX. Since is is supposed to run only on pages running Oracle APEX, I identify such pages with matching patterns in the subdirectory and parameters. This is easy for Chrome where I add this to my **manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*/*f?p=*", "*://*/*wwv_flow.accept*"],
  "js": ["content_script.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

But if I try the same in Firefox with the PageMod API in the **main.js** I can't get any matches and I try various combinations:

**main.js**

```
pageMod.PageMod({ 
           include: ["*://*/*f?p=*", "*://*/*wwv_flow.accept*"],
           contentScriptFile: data.url("content_script.js"),
           contentScriptWhen: "end",
```

Right now I'm running the content_script in Firefox on any Page and check the URL using the Javascript match functionality, if there is not match I return immediately

**content_script.js**

```
    var url = unsafeWindow.location.href;
    if (url.match(new RegExp("f?p=")) || url.match(new RegExp("wwv_flow.accept")))
```

My question is, if it is possible to get a matching pattern for the PageMOD API or if there is any other solution so my content script won't run on any page?

Comment: For whatever reason, SDK match-patterns only support [a single wildcard (asterisk)](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/48e3fe484f9f0d3178cb827fd7c64ccf88700cb0/lib/sdk/util/match-pattern.js#L37) in a pattern. Use a regex like in @abraham answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [match pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern) supports regex so something like this should work. You  might have to play around with the exact syntax a little.

`["/.*f\?p\=.*/*", "/.*wwv_flow\.accept.*/"]`